# log4net XMLConfigurato.Configure doesn't exist

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm trying to set up log4net logging on my project. I think everything is setup correctly, I have the reference to the dll and I've got a config file for it.

For some reason when I try to cofigure it using log4net.Config.XMLConfigurator.Configure() it only recognises the call up to log4net.Config.XMLConfigurator. The intellisense cannot see the Configure method in the XMLConfigurator class and when I compile, it throws an error:

Error   40  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

What could be wrong?

Comment: where are you putting the call to configure - is it in the AssemblyInfo file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use Log4Net extensively, and have found that the easiest way of doing it is to name the config file the same as the application executable, e.g. Myapp.exe.log4net.

You can then put a line in your AssemblyInfo.cs file to pick up this file

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFileExtension="log4net",Watch=true)]
```

See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Don't forget to set your .log4net file to Copy to output directory!

Comment: This won't work in the latest version , please update your answer.

Comment: @abdou93 I wrote this answer nearly 11 years ago so I'm not that surprised things have changed.  I no longer use Log4net.